# Cloning RF remote controller using Esp32 and RFM69HCW

Tags: c, iot, esp32, esp-idf, espressif-idf

I'm trying to recieve data from my garage remote control into a RFM69HCW conected to a esp32 spi, using the framework espressif.

The problem is that the Two rfm69 modules can comunicate between them(reciving and transmit), but when I try to receive from my remote control it receives nothing. The configuration is supposedly fine, the same Frecuency and I have tried changing the modulation but there is no way that it works.

Has anyone done something similar to that?
The code that Im using is a replica of this one [RF69](https://github.com/nopnop2002/esp-idf-rf69)

Comment: For those who are familiar with such stuff, it might be helpful if you added some information about your garage remote control you are trying to communicate with.

Comment: Garage remotes are often using encryption, so I don't know what you are hoping to do here. Other than that, you don't mention anything of relevance: modulation technique, frequency, the RF design used etc etc. The question is simply too broad to be answered and there's a good chance that whatever you are attempting isn't possible to achieve.

Comment: I’m new in this stuff so I don’t have the exact specifications but what I’m trying to do is to recieve and store the codes that garage remote use to open and close the door (Like Flipper zero does), as I know this one has no encryption. 
And if they have I guess that it can be store and sent without decrypt. 
The Frecuency that it uses is the 433.39, but the modulation I try the most common ones.

Comment: "I guess that it can be store and sent without decrypt" If that worked, no one would need it at all. Any decent security feature should not fall for replay attacks.

Comment: Thats what a flipper do if im not wrong, here you can see in it doc: https://docs.flipper.net/sub-ghz/read-raw.